# Promise map and get current value of array

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Below I have a regular promise bluebird map. What I'd like to achieve is a way to access the current value of the `arr`, to say that another way, I'd like to access `arr` from within the map with all of the preceding returned values. Because of this functionality I would also want the whole array to run linearly and in series (`{concurrency: 1}`).

Is this a special kind of map? Does bluebird offer this natively?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

var arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']

Promise.map(arr, function (item) {
  console.log([item, arr])
  return Promise.resolve(['x', item].join('+'))
}, {concurrency: 1})

// logs:

// [ 'alpha', [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' ] ]
// [ 'beta', [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' ] ]
// [ 'gamma', [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' ] ]

// expected / desired:

// [ 'alpha', [ 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' ] ]
// [ 'beta', [ 'x+alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' ] ]
// [ 'gamma', [ 'x+alpha', 'x+beta', 'gamma' ] ]
```

Comment: There's no async operation here.  Why are you using promises for this at all?  You can just use `arr.map()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated, for the sake of simplicity, please suspend your disbelief and insert a more time consuming promise above. Plus `arr.map()` also doesn't offer this functionality.

Comment: Then edit your question to at least describe where an async operation goes.  I try to offer the best way of doing things so you have to describe the context appropriately for people to know what best to suggest.   As your question is written now, it describes no reason for using promises at all.  I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is perfectly valid code for `Promise.map` to return sync or async code. I am trying to get access to `arr` from within the callback with updated values from the map iteslf. The commented portion at the bottom is what I am getting, and the expected / desired is what I'd like.

Comment: Is this for a Node/IO project or will it be used in a browser?

Comment: OK, fine.  I don't participate in theoretical questions that don't explain what problem is really trying to be solved. It makes it impossible to provide the best answer.   I'll move on then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

function promiseMapActive (arr, cb) {
  var count = 0
  return Promise.reduce(arr, function (arrActive, action) {
    return Promise.resolve(cb(action, count, arrActive)).then(function (value) {
      arrActive[count] = value
      count = count + 1
      return arrActive
    })
  }, arr)
}

var arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']

promiseMapActive(arr, function (item, index, arr) {
  console.log([item, arr])
  return Promise.resolve(['x', item].join('+'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to update the array `arr` using the current index in the map:

```js
var arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'];

P.map(arr, function(item, index, length) {
  // For displaying output
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify([item, arr], null, 2))
  );
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

  // Update array by index
  arr[index] = ['x', item].join('+');
  return P.resolve(item);
}, {concurrency: 1});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/2.9.3/bluebird.js"></script>
```

*Tested on Node but shown here with browser lib for convenience.*

Note: with promises it's not required to call `resolve` when returning a value. You can just use `return item`. Run the snippet below to see.

```js
var arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'];

P.map(arr, function(item, index, length) {
  // For displaying output
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify([item, arr], null, 2))
  );
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

  // Update array by index
  arr[index] = ['x', item].join('+');
  return item;
}, {concurrency: 1});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/2.9.3/bluebird.js"></script>
```